# Differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt}+2v=32$ of motion of particle.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A steel ball is dropped from rest from a height of $3000$ feet such that its velocity, $v$ at any time $t$ seconds is given by the differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt}+2v=32$.

How to find $v$ in terms of $t$?.

Comment: Write $dv/dt=32-2v$ or $\dfrac{dv}{32-2v}=dt$ and use integration.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Also, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: So then i get t in terms of v? Then, rearrange back?

Answer (score 3):

You have the differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} = 32 - 2v = 2^5-2v = 2(2^4-v)$$

So you can use that this equation is equivalent with

> $$\frac{\mathrm dv}{2^4-v} = 2\mathrm dt$$

And integrate both sides from the initial time $t = 0$ on the time side and from the initial velocity $v(0) := 0$ (because initially the ball is in rest):

$$\int_0^v\frac{\mathrm dv'}{2^4-v'} = 2\int_0^t\mathrm dt' = 2t$$

Then just integrate the other side and isolate the $v$ and you'll get a function $v = v(t)$ doing that.

---

> **Hint:** for the integral you can use the transformation $u = 2^4 - v$ with $\mathrm du = - \mathrm dv$.
>
> **Hint:** $\ln(e^x) = e^{\ln(x)} = x$

Comment: But then i get t in terms of v

Comment: No. You'll get $v$ in terms of $t$ if you use the definition of inverse function.

Comment: Could you do the integral?

Comment: What is your knowledge of calculus?

Comment: Hokoloh. Dok tanyo kalo dah tahu haa takpe la wagner mu pi dur ngantuk ni

Comment: Hi @shahiraanuar I think your from Indonesia? I couldn't understand that you've said

Answer (score 0):

Given $\dfrac{dv}{dt}+2v=32$.. The integrating factor is $e^{\int2 dt}=e^{2t}$. Hence the solution to this differential equation is

$v\times e^{2t}=\int32e^{2t}dt=16e^{2t}+c\implies v=16+ce^{-2t}$

Check [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~thomases/W11_16C1_lec_1_7_11.pdf) if you want to know about first order linear differential equations

Comment: Yeah this definitely the solution!! Thank you

Comment: please consider accepting the answer and vote up if you think that the answer is useful.. and it will close the thread.. Thank you